# Detecting file MIME in C

Tags: c, mime-types

I have files with wrong extensions, and try to find the correct `MIME` in a C script.

For a PDF file with txt extension, `magic` (`#include <magic.h>`)

```
  const char *mime;
  magic_t magic;
  magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE); 
  magic_load(magic, NULL);
  magic_compile(magic, NULL);
  mime = magic_file(magic, filename);
  printf("%s\n", mime);
  magic_close(magic);
```

returned

```
application/octet-stream
```

which is not very helpful.

`GIO 2.0` (`#include <gio/gio.h>`)

```
  char *content_type = g_content_type_guess (file_name, NULL, 0, &is_certain);

  if (content_type != NULL)
    {
      char *mime_type = g_content_type_get_mime_type (content_type);

      g_print ("Content type for file '%s': %s (certain: %s)\n"
               "MIME type for content type: %s\n",
               file_name,
               content_type,
               is_certain ? "yes" : "no",
               mime_type);

      g_free (mime_type);
    }
```

returned

```
Content type for file 'test.txt': text/plain (certain: no)
MIME type for content type: text/plain
```

However, `file` command in Linux returns the correct MIME:

```
file test.txt
test.txt: PDF document, version 1.6
```

This should not be the expected behaviors of these well-established libraries in C. What do I do wrong?

Comment: The `file` command is a command line interface to the `magic` library, so you can do this with the `magic` library (and it's the only widespread tool for the task). You must be using it wrong, but I don't know what (I know nothing about the `magic` API). Check that it's loading the same database files (e.g. with `strace`).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' this is exactly my point. I might have missed something since `magic` is the most common library for this purpose. This is why I posted the code I used. I rephrase the question to clarify my point.

Comment: Try checking if the functions are actually succeeding.

Comment: On my machine not calling magic_compile returns correct value. So there may be difference in default compiled and uncompiled database? Using precompiled database, and using MAGIC_CONTINUE, I am also able to get pdf and octet-stream at once, contrary to case with database compilation.

Comment: @raliscenda WOW I confirm that I get the correct MIME by removing the compile line. Several tests showed reasonable outputs. I will further test the results.

Comment: @raliscenda if you post it as an answer, it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, that file utility is base on top of libmagic, but what really determines returned values is flags provided to libmagic_open (or appropriate set functions) and used database of MIME types.

Library provides means to use pre-compiled database and raw database (has to be compiled by calling libmagic_compile), which is your case. [Documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/magic_load.3.html) defines default dabase files when called using NULL parameter as a /usr/local/share/misc/magic for raw database (on debian directory link from /usr/share/misc/magic to ../file/magic/, and is empty) and magic.mgs in same parent directory.

Compiled library is by default placed into working directory and on my debian system seams to be empty (confirmed by default directory of database data being empty). After realizing this, I tried your example with magic_compile removed and it seams to improve things significantly.